# Why doesn't this <audio> play in Safari?

Tags: html, audio, safari

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<audio controls="controls" >
  <source src="coin.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</body>
</html``
```

This plays in Chrome without a hitch.

Comment: should be mpeg, not mp3 for the file type

Comment: HTML5 support is far from acceptable yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be mpeg, not mp3 for the file type

```
<audio controls="controls" >
<source src="coin.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: So 3 years after this post the safary didn't support html5 audio without Quicktime. For me the Safary team goes in wrong direction. Using and developing for a Safary is suffering. For developing: F12 doesn.t open the developer tools like in other browsers, to clear cache I must open Reset safary. ( this is like reaching Shut down via Start button in windows ).

Answer (score 6):

It's most likely because Safari's HTML5 audio/video support relies on Quicktime, which means anyone using Safari will need to have Quicktime installed.

Comment: No, the I posted the answer in the first comment. Thanks though. You must have be going through some new/old posts :)

Comment: Your post was still on the front page actually. Glad you found your answer!